# Generating Devise Controllers - Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying devise for the first time.I am following the link:https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. Here,i have executed the command:

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

when i have executed this,the model and view parts are created.When i checked the routes,I have noticed that there is a controller created with the name:MODEL.but i didnot find the controller in the project.My query is how can we find whether a controller is generated or not and use that controller in the project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you replace *MODEL* in the command with actual model name. Something like *User*?

Comment: Yeah.I had replaced MODEL with User

Comment: So, what is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: In my project I am unable to find the controller that is created by devise.But when i had executed rake routes, the controller is displayed.

Comment: when you ran `rails generate devise User`, didn't it show the path of models, controllers generated on your terminal?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many commands that `devise` provides..

1. `rails generate devise:install` - will create `config/devise.rb`
2. `rails generate devise User` - will create `db/migration-file-for-user-model` which *commented* code,which you can *uncomment*,if you need other modules..such as `confirmable`,`omniauth` etc
3. `rails generate devise:views` - will create all views in the `devise` folder with `app/views/devise/sessions`,`app/views/devise/confirmations`,`registrations` etc folder and its views respectively.
4. `rails generate devise:views users` - will create folder of `app/views/users/passwords/`,`app/views/users/confirmations` ..etc instead of `devise` folder above.
5. `rails generate devise:controllers` -  will create all `controllers`..**similar to above**...here it will create `app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb` with default commented code,which you need to *edit* else leave it as it is for basic authentication.Moreover,you can also add `users` *scope* in the end,to generate controllers in `controllers/users/` and not `controllers/devise/`

You may also go through this good [**devise tutorial**](https://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/) ..

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helped.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

running

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

when using the Devise gem will not create the controllers for you.

In your case, if you want to change any methods in the Devise controllers, you may want to create your own controller that inherits Devise controllers.

For example, changing the devise registration controllers to allow first and last name would require you to create your own controller under app/controllers/MODEL/registrations_controller.rb

[Link to Devise controllers here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise)

```
class MODEL::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

and instructing your routes.rb to use the controller

```
devise_for :MODEL, :controllers => { :registrations => "MODEL/registrations" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer.

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace MODEL with User like

```
rails generate devise User
```

It will generate User model under app/modeld/user.rb and user controller under app/controllers/users_controller.rb

run migration to add user table under database using command:

```
rake db:migrate
```