# Conflict with naming of sessions route in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, routes

I installed Devise on an existing rails 4.2 app.

I want to gradually roll out a new login system (using devise), where the current login system (custom made) is still working in parallel. There are certain parts of the application where I want to use the new system.

The previous setup has the following routes defined:

```
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :password_resets
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'verify_email/:token', :action => 'verify_email', :as => :verify_email
  end
end
```

So I created a new user model called `CustomerUser`.

Then I added the devise routes:

```
devise_for :customer_users
resource :customer_users
```

The sign up views work properly, however the login (sessions) is clashing with the existing routes.

**The link generated from the sign-up screen towards the login screen is broken (is pointing to `/da/sessions/new.customer_user` and clicking on it I get a `ActionController::UnknownFormat in SessionsController#new` error)**

Also when I visit the login page directly `/da/customer_users/sign_in`, and submit the form, it sends a POST to the `/da/sessions/customer_user` path, ending in a `No route matches` error.

I tried adding these overrides to the devise routes, however they still don't work.

```
devise_for :customer_users do
  match 'sessions/customer_user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
  match 'sessions/customer_user', to: 'devise/sessions#new', via: :get
end
```

I can confirm that commenting out this route fixes the issue, however I still want the old routes to work:

```
# resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

The routes being created by devise are the following:

```
new_customer_user_session_da_path   GET /da/customer_users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new {:locale=>"da"}
customer_user_session_da_path   POST    /da/customer_users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#create {:locale=>"da"}
destroy_customer_user_session_da_path   DELETE  /da/customer_users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy {:locale=>"da"}
```

The previous setup (not devise) is creating these routes:

```
sessions_da_path    POST    /da/sessions(.:format)  sessions#create {:locale=>"da"}
new_session_da_path GET /da/sessions/new(.:format)  sessions#new {:locale=>"da"}
session_da_path DELETE  /da/sessions/:id(.:format)  sessions#destroy {:locale=>"da"}
```

I also observed that the views created by devise use this helper:

```
session_path(resource_name)
```

which I have a hard time understanding how it works in terms of normal Rails routes and the routes that devise generated (see above).

**How can I change the settings for Devise so that the new session routes are not conflicting with the existing ones?**

Comment: Well this is strange. I have multiple devise models and all have their own sessions routes. My app has a different setup though. First you can add a path to the devise model `devise_for :customer_users, path: 'customer_users' `. Also I have generated controller and views for each of my Devise model: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers Each model route sends to the very controller of each model and I dont see any conflict. And I like to be able to see them physically on my app so that I can tweak everything. Not sure if this helps

Comment: This threads can be helpful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972575/generating-devise-controllers-rails-devise (Although I am not sure as your Devise model and old model have their own routes..)

Comment: @Maxence thanks. I think though my issues is related to my existing routes which are not handled by devise. Having `resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]` in my routes is creating the conflict. I would like to understand how the `session_path(resource_name)` works because I believe my solution is somewhere in the assumptions that helper makes.

Comment: I managed to find out where those helpers are defined: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.4.3/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb#L10

Comment: Yes those routes obfuscations can become explicit when you generate the Devise controllers for each model and declare the routing :  `devise_for :clients, path: 'clients', controllers: {registrations: "clients/registrations", passwords: "clients/passwords", confirmations: "clients/confirmations", sessions: "clients/sessions"}` Then when you trigger a `Rails routes` in console, you can see things like : `new_client_session GET    /clients/sign_in(.:format)   clients/sessions#new`