# Verify expired link was valid

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-7, password-less

I am building Rails API app, where I'm using devise-passwordless library.

If I send magic link to user and user waits too long to come to my app, how can I verify that the used token was valid and generate/send new one?

I'm looking for something like:

```
User.find_by(
    email: magic_link_request_params[:email], 
    old_token: magic_link_request_params[:old_token] )
.send_magic_link(true)
```

to be sure, that the user was already invited before by authorized admin/manager. If so, I want to be able to resend the magic link, otherwise I don't want to let the user in my app, so looking him up just by email is not enough.

- Ruby 3.2.2
- Rails 7
- ActionController::API
- Devise::Controllers::Rails7ApiMode
- Devise
- Devise-passwordless

Answer (score 1):

Uglier, slower approach than my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76195249/1880203), but much simpler:

1. Generate `sessions_controller` and `magic_links_controller` ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41972901/1880203)
2. Create your migration to add `last_magic_link` and `last_magic_link_sent_at` to your `User` model
3. Change the `SessionsController#create` code:

```rb
def create
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by(email: create_params[:email])
    if self.resource
      resource.send_magic_link(create_params[:remember_me])
      # assumes that the token generated here will match the token generated by #send_magic_link
      # this is a BIG ASSUMPTION since both use `Time.current` and can differ by milliseconds, could prevent this strategy from working
      token = Devise::Passwordless::LoginToken.encode(resource)
      resource.update(last_magic_link: token, last_magic_link_sent_at: Time.current)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :magic_link_sent, now: true)
    else
      set_flash_message(:alert, :not_found_in_database, now: true)
    end

    self.resource = resource_class.new(create_params)
    render :new
  end
```

4. Change the `MagicLinksController#show` method:

```rb
  def show
    begin
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    rescue InvalidOrExpiredTokenError -> error
      # decode the token yourself (it's probably auth_options.token, dunno, you'll have to find it. It should be in params too)
      decoded = Devise::Passwordless::LoginToken.decode(token)
      # check to see if the token matches the user record
      # the decoded token has "key" and "email" resources
      email_from_token = decoded["data"]["resources"]["email"]
      user = User.find_by(email: email_from_token)
      user.last_magic_link == token
      # then do what you want, e.g. send another link
    end
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

Here's a ***big*** caveat:

The token has data["created_at"] saved as a float and it seems like that's part of the encryption used to encode the token.

So, the token you generate immediately after the `resource.send_magic_link` COULD differ from the token that the gem generates. I can't tell without testing if and exactly how to compare the token you've saved with the token you're receiving back from the email link.

Comment: Thanks for help, take my like. I will get back to you once I implement it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If this doesn't work because the tokens don't match, see my first answer, which is harder to code, but will be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Devise isn't saving the token anywhere.

It [encodes and decodes the token](https://github.com/abevoelker/devise-passwordless/blob/master/lib/devise/passwordless/login_token.rb) without any reliance on a User record.

It also doesn't have a method to ***just*** generate the token ***without*** emailing it, so you're going to be modifying this gem quite a bit to get your behavior.

First, you'll need a migration to add fields to your User object. In my example, I'm using `last_magic_link` and `last_magic_link_sent_at`

If you feel comfortable writing your own modules and `prepend`ing them, the cleanest solution is to create an **initializer** that changes the `send_magic_link` to update your `User` record between when the token is generated and when the email is sent:

```rb
# /config/initializers/devise/passwordless/mailer_override.rb
# from: https://github.com/abevoelker/devise-passwordless/blob/master/lib/devise/passwordless/mailer.rb#L6

# we need `require "devise/passwordless"` and `require "devise/mailer"`
# I believe we get them all by requiring all of "devise"
require "devise"

# a custom module to override Devise::Passwordless::Mailer#magic_link
# NOTE: I pasted this untested and untried code from SO, I should check to make sure this works as intended
module MailerAndRecordUpdater
  def magic_link(record, token, remember_me, opts = {})
    @token = token
    @remember_me = remember_me
    devise_mail(record, :magic_link, opts)
    # record is a User record
    record.update(last_magic_link: @token, last_magic_link_sent_at: Time.now)
  end
end

[Devise::Passwordless::Mailer, Devise::Passwordless::Mailer.singleton_class].each do |mod|
  mod.prepend MailerAndRecordUpdater
end
```

And, the authors did you a favor by adding a method called [`after_magic_link_authentication`](https://github.com/abevoelker/devise-passwordless/blob/master/lib/devise/models/magic_link_authenticatable.rb#L22) that you can use to remove those record attributes from the `User` once they successfully sign in:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def after_magic_link_authentication
    # intentionally leaving :last_magic_link_sent_at for history
    update(last_magic_link: nil)
  end
end
```

---

Now you are saving and removing tokens as they are generated and used.

But you've still got your primary use case: see if the token && email matches if it's expired.

Unfortunately, the gem raises a very broad error: `InvalidOrExpiredTokenError` and it doesn't tell you which is actually the case: invalid or expired.

You can write a similar override on [`Devise::Passwordless::LoginToken#decrypt`](https://github.com/abevoelker/devise-passwordless/blob/master/lib/devise/passwordless/login_token.rb#L42) and add a message to `raise InvalidOrExpiredTokenError` if the token is expired:

```rb
      created_at = ActiveSupport::TimeZone["UTC"].at(decrypted_data["created_at"])
      if as_of.to_f > (created_at + expire_duration).to_f
        raise InvalidOrExpiredTokenError, "expired" #<- custom message
      end
```

Then, in the `Devise::Passwordless::MagicLinksController` (that you'll have to [ask Devise to generate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41972901/1880203)) you can rescue from that error:

```rb
  def show
    begin
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    rescue InvalidOrExpiredTokenError -> error
      # check to see if the error's message is "expired"
      # check to see if the token matches the user record
      # then do what you want if both of the above are true
    end
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```